# can't write file on php

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, php5

I am trying to create a file in the /tmp directory and unable to.  It won't even let me create a file in the same dir I am in (/var/www/html).  I believe I dont have the correct setting on my php.ini, but I dont know what I need to change to make this work.

My OS is CentOS7 and I am running Apache with php 5.4.16.  I do have read/write on /var/www/html and the user/group is set to apache.  Below is just a generic code to write a file which is not working, I keep getting "Unable to open file"

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Maybe it's blocked by SELinux, is it Enforcing? Do `getenforce`.

Comment: it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not specifying a path to /tmp for newfile.txt so how would it know where to write it?

The second thing is, CentOS 7 uses systemd and if you check in the file /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.conf

You will see the line

PrivateTmp=true

That means your file is likely written (or will be) into a directory /tmp/systemd-private... or something like that.

If you don't much care for this, you can change it to false and reload with

systemctl daemon-reload and then you'll likely need to restart httpd.